# What is the more efficient method for using API data?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, sql-injection

I am using SQL to pull API data from a database and build DOM elements with javascript. I want to know if it is faster to:

1. **Use a broad query**, sort the data and build the page with js

   ```
   format=json&q=SELECT * FROM table
   ```
2. **Use a specific query**, not have to sort it as much and then build the page with js.

   ```
   format=json&q=SELECT * FROM table WHERE date >= '23/03/2018'
   ```

Any insight is helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The difference in time it would take in order for MySQL to execute the query makes little to no difference (depending on the size of your database). However, considering Javascript is building up elements based on the results, it would be better to sort the data into as little amounts as possible to keep it fast.

By the way, are you executing SQL commands from client-side code? Please do post your entire code as I can't understand exactly what you're doing, but if you are executing exactly what user's input into the `?q=` parameter, then your code is incredibly dangerous and vulnerable to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).

I'd recommend you do this serverside, using a language such as `PHP`, which will execute it server-side, so none of the existing worries relating to the pace of Javascript building DOM elements would exist, and not to mention PHP is a server-side language and as such the input can be validated & secured to remove anything malicious. Remember that even if you did validate with Javascript, it'd be easy for a user to overwrite the code as it would be validated client-side (on the user's own computer which they have access to).

Comment: Ok, i was thinking along the same lines; less data to handle in general equals faster js at the very least. 

I am using PHP that runs a js file when on a specific page.
if page = example { run example.js }, example.js would then call, sort and display the data.

Comment: Sounds a bit better of a set-up than your OP suggested. If you want to post some of the PHP/JS code here, or in private, I can let you know if there is anything which is obviously not secure/bad practice.

Comment: Using Wordpress; can I store the API key or the whole SQL query in a more secure location. instead of on the page script (in this case, example.js has the URL:

 https://api.website/api/v2/query/?token=API-KEY&format=json&q=SELECT * FROM \"daily log\" WHERE date >= '" + dateSearchInput + "\'")

Comment: The JS isn't the problem. The issue is that your ?q= parameter is accepting a raw SQL command, which is terrible practice. Try a GET request to a URL like: https://api.website/api/v2/query/?token=API-KEY&format=json&q=SELECT * FROM users (assuming there is a table with users, I've just dumped your entire database and have all your user's passwords (encrypted or not). Let me know if queries like that are working, I could also drop all tables and break the site along with several other SQL injections. And don't try to make the query smaller and limit it only to what is needed, it can be esculate